# How to click the link icon in CK editor

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

When I click the link icon in ck editor initially it worked, but when I re-run the code, it's not clicking the link icon in the ck editor.

This is the command I used initially:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='cke_29']/span[1]")).click();
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like the id is dynamic one,Check the id while running the test.

Comment: initially mean when ? and please post error stack trace

Comment: don't use any span just use xpath just ''a"

Comment: generally CKeditor are under iframe so make sure

Answer (score 1):

Use `WebDriverWait` to handle dynamic element.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[starts-with(@id,'cke_')][@class='cke_button cke_button__link cke_button_off']"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@akshay-patil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10389622/akshay-patil) commented use the `a` tag. The reason is that the `<a>` tag is the link itself... not the span!

You should use:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='cke_29']")).click();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @User2080 so try using Kajal Kundu's answer! it's best practice!

Comment: @NarendraR Initially in the sense 1 or 5 runs it worked yesterday. But today its not working

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so to `click()` on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.cke_button.cke_button__link.cke_button_off[id^='cke_'][title^='Link']>span.cke_button_icon.cke_button__link_icon"))).click();
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='cke_button cke_button__link cke_button_off' and starts-with(@id,'cke_')][starts-with(@title,'Link')]/span[@class='cke_button_icon cke_button__link_icon']"))).click();
  ```